# Analyze singularities of $\frac{\log(z)}{(1-z)^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Analyze each singularity $z_0$ of $f$. Is it removable, a pole, or essential? If it is a pole, what is its order? If it is removable, what value should you give the function at $z_0$ to make it analytic?
>
> $$f(z)=\frac{\log(z)}{(1-z)^2}$$ where $\log$ is defined on the principal branch.

Here's what I have so far:

Consider $z_0=1$. The Taylor expansion of $\log(z)$ about $1$ is given by $(z-1)-\frac{(z-1)^2}{2}+\frac{(z-1)^3}{3}-\cdots$. Thus,
$$ f(z) = \frac{1-\frac{(z-1)}{2}+\frac{(z-1)^2}{2}-\cdots}{z-1}.$$

If we let the numerator equal $h(z)$, then we see that $h(z)$ is analytic on a neighborhood about $z_0=1$ Moreover, $h(1)=1\neq 0$. Thus, $f(z)$ has a simple pole at $z_0 =1$ and $\text{ord}_1(f)=-1$.

I guess my question is: is this correct? Are there other points $z_0$ I need to consider? I just feel slightly hesitant about my answer. Thanks.

Comment: $\;ord_1\;$ the residue, right? Anyway, what about the rather disturbing singularity $\;z=0\;$ ?

Comment: @Timbuc $\text{ord}_1$ just refers to the order of the pole. We haven't yet discussed residues in my class. As for $z_0=0$, I had realized this was a bad point, but I'm not sure how to deal with it. Is it perhaps an essential singularity? $\log(z)$ is never defined at this point.

Comment: But then you already wrote what the order is: it is one as it is a **simple** pole. What you wrote $\;ord_1\;$ is referred  to as the residue of the function in that pole.

Comment: @Timbuc Ah, my mistake. I was just told to write that after determining the order of the pole.

Comment: Fine @Hildegarde, perhaps that's a way to introduce a little later residues.

Comment: @Timbuc Perhaps. Anyway, do you have any ideas how to deal with or classify the singularity at $z_0=0$? To me, it doesn't even seem like an isolated singularity, because $\log(z)$ is undefined for the entire negative real axis.

Comment: $\;z=0\;$ is not even an essential singularity of $\;\log z\;$, but even "worse": it is what could be called a branch point or branch singularity. There is no Laurent series for the logarithm around $\;z=0\;$ . BTW, it is *not* that $\;\log z\;$ is undefined in the negative real axis, but rather that that axis, together with zero, is *susually* chosen as a branch cut so that in what's left  of the complex plane we have a nice behaving $\;\log z\;$ .